# Definite integral-dot product

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

I have an integral equation containing dot product

$$\int_{0}^{L} \left(\frac{a}{L}.b(s)\right)\mathrm ds\tag 1$$

**Data Given**

1. a is a constant vector of size 3
2. b(s) is a varying vector of size 3
3. " . "  means dot product

**Question**

Can we write $$\int_{0}^{L} \left(\frac{a}{L}.b(s)\right)\mathrm ds =  a . \int_{0}^{L} b(s)\mathrm ds\tag 2$$ Is it right to write like this? I am not familiar with calculus on dot product

Comment: You are missing a factor of $\frac{1}{L}$ on the right side.

Comment: $\frac{1}{L}$  will get  canceled  by expansion of definite integral

Comment: So am I right Jimmy?

Comment: Try letting $a$ and $b(s)$ be constant scalars. You'll see that $L$ does not get cancelled out.

Comment: If a and b(s) are constant scalars then what is the meaning of dot product

Comment: Scalars are just vectors with $1$ component, so it becomes multiplication. Either way, try out a few examples where $L \neq 1$ and see if that equality holds.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{L} (\frac{a}{L}.b)ds =\int_{0}^{L}  \frac{a}{L}ds.\int_{0}^{L}b(s) ds = [\frac{as}{L}+C ]_0^L.\int_{0}^{L}b(s) ds=a.\int_{0}^{L}b(s) ds$

Comment: @Rejo_Slash Your error is in the first equality.  The integral operator is not multiplicative.  For instance, take $L \neq 0, 1$ and $a=b=1$.  The left-hand side is $1$ while the right-hand side is $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the right-hand side has some type issues.

For simplicity let's assume all vectors live in a vector space of at least dimension two.

The left-hand side makes sense since $f(s):= \mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b(s)$ is a real-valued function.

What is $\int_0^L \mathbf b(s) \ ds$?  For instance, what does it mean to integrate the constant vector $\mathbf b = (1, 1)$ over the interval $[0, 1]$?  If this is a number, then you are taking the dot product of a vector with a number, which is not defined in this case.  If we are to interpret this integral as another vector, what should it be?

If you have access to the component functions of $\mathbf b(s)$ then can simplify things a bit.  Suppose that $\mathbf a = (a_1, a_2, a_3)$ (where $a_i \in \mathbb R$) and $\mathbf b(s)=(f_1(s), f_2(s), f_3(s))$ (where $f_i \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a function).  Then of course
$$
\int_0^L (1/L)\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b(s) \ ds = (1/L) \int_0^L \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i f_i (s) \ ds = (1/L) \sum_{i=1}^3 \int_0^L a_i f_i(s) \ ds.
$$

Comment: Would you tell me what could be  the simplified form for equation (1)

Comment: We are dealing only vectors with 3 elements

Comment: @Rejo_Slash That the dimension is three is largely irrelevant to the answer above.  Moreover, what sort of simplification are you looking for?  The left-hand side of (1) is already fairly simple.  I'll take a stab at it though with an update.

Comment: I have added a reply as answer

Answer (score 2):

Let me expand it from where helpful answer of @shawn stopped

$ \int_0^L (1/L)\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b(s) \ ds = (1/L) \int_0^L \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i f_i (s) \ ds \tag1$

$(1/L) \sum_{i=1}^3 \int_0^L a_i f_i(s) \ ds.=  \frac{a_1}{L}  \int_0^Lf_1(s) \ ds+\frac{a_2}{L}  \int_0^Lf_2(s) \ ds+\frac{a_3}{L}  \int_0^Lf_3(s) \ ds\tag 2$

By using definition 126 in this([link](http://math.kennesaw.edu/~plaval/math2203/vectfuncdiff.pdf)) article. We can rewrite the equation as

$ =(\frac{a_1}{L}i+\frac{a_2}{L}j+\frac{a_3}{L}k).(\int_0^Lf_1(s)\ ds\hspace{.2cm}i+\int_0^Lf_2(s)\ ds\hspace{.2cm}j+\int_0^Lf_3(s)\ ds\hspace{.2cm}k) \tag3$

which is equal to

$\frac{a}{L} . \int_{0}^{L} b(s)\mathrm ds\tag 4$