# Bringing one of the factors of the dot product inside an integral, outside the integral

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, kinematics

This question might be similar to [MSE Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905579/definite-integral-dot-product) but I didn't really get the answer.

Suppose I want to evaluate the integral $$W = \int \underline{F}\cdot \underline{dr}$$ which actually has the physical meaning of giving the work done by the force $F$ along $r$. Now, Imagine I have a non conservative vector field (or force), i.e. $F$ is non conservative, it is a resistive force which resists with constant value $R$, suppose it acts for a distance $d$. Then can I do the following? $$W = \int \underline{F}\cdot\underline{dr}  =\underline{F}\cdot\int\underline{dr} = \underline{F}\cdot\underline{\triangle r} = -Rd$$

and if so

> why can I do that? When can I take out one of the factors of a dot product inside an integral?

I.e. can I take out the force? This happens in the last line of this page of  my lecture notes:
[image: Image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: You can take out F if it is a constant vector, otherwise not.

Comment: @Paul what I don't understand is, how do we know it works? Of course we know it for standard multiplication, but here we have a dot product, it's not trivial that we can take it out, or is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the force is constant, 
\begin{align*}
\int {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r} 
&= \int \sum_i F_i dr_i \\
&= \sum_i F_i \int dr_i \\
&= {\bf F}\cdot \int d{\bf r} \\
&= {\bf F}\cdot \Delta{\bf r}.
\end{align*}
This is allowed due to the definition of the dot product and the fact that for constant $c$, 
$\int c f(x) dx = c\int f(x) dx$.

Comment: but how can you do the step in the second line? Recall that you have$$\int \sum_i(F_idr_i)$$, whereas you are treating it as if it was $$\int (\sum_iF_i)dr$$. For example if $F = (a,b)$ and $dr = (dx,dy)$ then we would have $$\int adx+bdy$$ but you can't factor out $a$ and $b$ like you did. You'd have to do $$a\int dx + b\int dy$$

Comment: @Euler_Salter: We have 
\begin{align*}
\int{\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r} 
&= \int \sum F_i d r_i \\
&= \int(F_x dx + F_y dy)  \\
&= \int F_x dx + \int F_y dy  \\
&= F_x \int dx + F_y \int dy \\
&= \sum_i F_i \int dr_i.
\end{align*}

Comment: so in the last line you mean $$\sum_i \left(F_i\int dr_i\right)$$?

Comment: That is correct!